# SQL group by, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql

The situation is as follows:

Find the top 5 Community Areas by average College Enrollment.

The DB is stored as SCHOOLS.

```
%sql SELECT COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT, COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME FROM SCHOOLS GROUP BY COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT;
```

I understand that this would give me the college enrollment by community, but I get the error message of this:

(ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: Exception('SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0119N  An expression starting with "COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.  SQLSTATE=42803\r SQLCODE=-119')

Can anyone give me a lead on what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When using `GROUP BY` anything you put after the `SELECT` clause has to be used in the `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate function, like `SUM()`.  In your case you would need to place `COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME` in the `GROUP BY` clause or remove it from the `SELECT` clause to get the error to go away.  That said, I don't think this query is quite what you want - I would do something like this:

```
SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, SUM(COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT) AS TOTAL_ENROLLED FROM SCHOOLS GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, ORDER BY TOTAL_ENROLLED DESC;
```

Explanation:

- `SUM(COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT)`:  Total up the enrollment of all schools
  that are in a single `COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME`.
- `AS TOTAL_ENROLLED`: Give the result from SUM() a name so we can easily refer to it later in the `ORDER BY` clause.
- `ORDER BY TOTAL_ENROLLED DESC`:  Sort the output by `TOTAL_ENROLLED` and put the biggest numbers
  at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following it should work.

`Find the top 5 Community Areas by average College Enrollment.`

```
SELECT 
    COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME,
    AVG(COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT) AS AVG_ENROLL
FROM SCHOOLS 
GROUP BY 
     COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME
ORDER BY
    AVG(COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT) DESC
LIMIT 5
;
```